# autohotkey: release a key sends "return"?

Tags: search, text, vim, key, editor

I would like to realise: (for use in a text editor)

- press a specific Key: call a search function (e.g.: CTL-F or in VIM "/" or "?")
- WHILE HOLDING THIS KEY I type the string to be searched - incremental search starts
- on RELEASE of this key it calls "RETURN" (and cursor moves to the desired position)

If anyone of you has heard of "Leaping" (Jef Raskin/Archy, Canon Cat), this is it, like in VIM "/" but without the "RETURN" press...

Comment: But how would you insert `f` or `/` or `?` in the search if you have to keep the key pressed?

Comment: @Quasimodo e.g. assign "Capslock" to a search-function. - press "Capslock" & hold, type "searchstring", release  "Capslock". (Need a key that fires 2 time: on press call function 1, on release call function 2, in this case return)?

Comment: Vim is essentially a terminal application, so it doesn't know anything about "release" events, except "mouse release". So binding to `<LeftMouse>` / `<LeftRelease>` is trivial, but no luck otherwise.